# Can a linear differential equation of $y(x)$ ever involve powers of $y$ and/or $x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Defining a linear differential equation as one in which linear combinations of solutions are also solutions, can a linear differential equation involving $y(x)$ ever involve powers of $y$ and/or $x$? Is there a proof of this?

Comment: The definition of a linear differential equation is that each term has a power 1 of y. So no, you're never going to see y², or else it wouldn't be linear. There's no rules on x.

Comment: @Kaynex I've added "Defining a linear differential equation as one in which linear combinations of solutions are also solutions…" Basically, I want to know if it's possible to prove, starting with that definition of a linear differential equation, whether a linear differential equation can involves powers of $y$ and/or $x$.

Comment: I'm not sure you are going to see a "proof" of this, and if you do it's probably going to look an awful lot like sophistry. This is a definition - to say it is a linear differential equation *is* to say it does not involve higher order powers of $y$, it can involve the dependent variable $x$ and still be called a linear ODE, but in this case we would call it "nonautonomous"

Comment: This is a question of functional properties, not so much differential equations. Can you think of any functions that have the property $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$? It's possible to solve that the only possible function is $f(x) = Cx$ which shows the only DE that has a "linear property" is a linear differential equation.